# AngularJS - How to limit service visibility?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create an angular service which will be visible only in some modules (but not in all). I have tried to create a service in a module and then include it in a different module, but the service is still visible in the entire application. 
Example:

```
var myAppSubModule = angular.module('myAppSubModule',[]);
myAppSubModule.factory('TestSubService', function() {
    return {
        testFnc: function() {
            return 'test';  
        }
    }
});

var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule',['myAppSubModule']);
myAppModule.factory('TestService', function(TestSubService) {
    return {
        testFnc: function() {
            return TestSubService.testFnc(); //this should work
        }
    }
});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myAppModule']);

function MyCtrl($scope, TestSubService, TestService) {
    $scope.name = TestService.testFnc(); //this should work
    $scope.name2 = TestSubService.testFnc(); //this should fail
}
```

I want TestSubService to be visible in TestService, but not in the entire application.
Is there any way to achieve this?